# Unable to get clarification on Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, reputation

I note in the "questions that may already have your answer" section that 22 others have asked similar questions i.e. why can't new members comment.  I read many of them.  I understand your justification for requiring reps.  However, you seem to be overlooking a couple of considerations in making this pronouncement.

- Sometimes the reply marked as the answer is just plainly wrong.  This may be because the discussed software has changed or the OP may have implemented the answer in conjunction with other changes and thought it was the answer that fixed the issue.  I have implemented several dozen answers found here that did not fix the issue. I have also seen answers referring to the use of classes and properties that no longer exist. But I am not allowed to inform others of this, or to ask for clarification on everything that was done.  This just happened today and there is nothing I can do about it.
- Sometime the answers are not clear.  Perhaps it was clear to to people with extensive experience in the tools causing the problem but to a newby you might as well be speaking gibberish.  It would help to be able to ask for some clarification on just what was meant.

Perhaps if you want to prevent extraneous comments you could provide a means just to request clarification.  Maybe a checkbox or something?

One of the explanations you provided is that it is not hard for a user to gain 50 rep points.  Actually it is very hard to do so when your job is not at the cutting edge of technology.  My customer is working with versions of software that are two or three versions out of date.  By the time I become proficient in them, no one else is using it any more.  In addition, cruising the internet to answer questions on StackOverflow, social.microsoft.com, or Experts-Exchange during working hours is a sure fire guarenteed way to get fired.

Comment: `Perhaps if you want to prevent extraneous comments you could provide a means just to request clarification. Maybe a checkbox or something?` How could that be useful? If I received a message saying "someone wanted clarification on your answer", I would have no idea what clarification to provide, nor would I know if my attempt at clarifying was successful.

Comment: The linked duplicate explains why the limit exists, and what the rationale is to keep it in place even though it arguably is a hurdle to some, and will occasionally lose valuable content or clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the situation you describe in your question your best bet to get to 50 points would be to edit questions. You get +2 points every time an edit is accepted. Some questions suffer from language issues: spelling, grammar. Some questions suffer from formatting issues because the poster did not know how to use the proper markup to format their code. You do not need to be an expert in any field to do this.